# Treatment options for generalised primary hyperhidrosis

Tags: sweat, sudoriferous-sweat-glands

I have seen that a pharmacist can help with hyperhidrosis (excessive sweating). According to the [NHS website](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/excessive-sweating-hyperhidrosis/) you can buy things without a prescription which can help, such as:

> - stronger antiperspirants instead of deodorant
> - armpit or sweat shields to protect your clothing
> - foot powders for sweaty feet
> - soap substitutes that are more gentle on your skin.

But what if they don't help?

Surgically, I have heard of endoscopic bilateral thoracic sympathicolysis (EBTS)

> Endoscopic bilateral thoracic sympathicolysis (EBTS) is an effective and minimally invasive procedure used for patients with primary hyperhidrosis ([Ramos, et al. 2006](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejcts.2006.05.018); [Ureña, et al. 2009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejcts.2009.02.062)).

However, there are a fair few risks involved from what I understand, where:

> Thoracic sympathectomy will change many bodily functions, including sweating,<sup>[14]</sup> vascular responses,<sup>[15]</sup> heart rate,<sup>[16]</sup> heart stroke volume,<sup>[17][18]</sup> thyroid, baroreflex,<sup>[19]</sup> lung volume,<sup>[18][20]</sup> pupil dilation, skin temperature and other aspects of the [autonomic nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomic_nervous_system), like genitourinary functions and the essential [fight-or-flight response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight-or-flight_response) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoscopic_thoracic_sympathectomy)).

The procedure can also lead to [Horner's Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_syndrome) or [Harlequin Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlequin_syndrome) and I have found that for 92% of patients ([National Institute for Health and Care Excellence [NICE], 2014](https://www.nice.org.uk/guidance/ipg487)), the surgery can cause them to sweat more heavily than the hyperhidrosis did, defeating the object of the surgery while risking more serious complications **all surgeries** carry.

So, what other options are available (if any) for those who suffer from generalised primary (idiopathic) hyperhidrosis?

*Generalised* meaning *all over the body* rather than localised to hands, feet or armpits; and *idiopathic* meaning *of no known underlying medical cause* such as obesity, menopause, a tumor, diabetes mellitus, or hyperthyroidism (overactive thyroid gland).

Are there alternatives to EBTS which can help with hyperhidrosis, and maybe with less risk to other functions of the autonomic nervous system?

### References

NICE (2014). Endoscopic thoracic sympathectomy for primary hyperhidrosis of the upper limb: Interventional procedures guidance [IPG487] https://www.nice.org.uk/guidance/ipg487

Ramos, R., Moya, J., Morera, R., Masuet, C., Perna, V., Macia, I., Escobar, I., & Villalonga, R. (2006). An assessment of anxiety in patients with primary hyperhidrosis before and after endoscopic thoracic sympathicolysis. *European journal of cardio-thoracic surgery, 30*(2), 228–231. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejcts.2006.05.018

Ureña, A., Ramos, R., Masuet, C., Macia, I., Rivas, F., Escobar, I., Villalonga, R., & Moya, J. (2009). An assessment of plantar hyperhidrosis after endoscopic thoracic sympathicolysis. *European journal of cardio-thoracic surgery 36*(2), 360–363. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejcts.2009.02.062